# Is Amazon Web Services autoscaling in terms of price?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I would just like to know if I understand Amazon Web Services correctly. If I have an EC2 instance using the free tier, if my bandwidth or storage goes above the free tier limit, do I only pay per hour whilst it is going above the limit? Do I have to organise an upgrade or does it do it automatically? In other words, do you only pay for what you use?

Answer (score 1):

The AWS Free-Tier is only available to new customers and for 12 months following your AWS sign-up date. If your usage gets exceeds the free-tier you will be paying standard, pay-as-you-go service rates. There is no need of upgradations of account.

[Amazon Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/pricing/services/)
Hope it helps :-)